# phpmyadmin error 13 permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, apache, permissions, phpmyadmin

I was working with my php server & phpmyadmin for MYSQL. I wanted to install some packages with composer, than somehow I changed permissions on my project folder and than database from phpmyadmin disappeared. I lost everything. I am trying to recover it for 3 hours. I am receiving these errors when I am trying to import create_tables.sql

```
#13 - Can't get stat of './phpmyadmin' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

and

```
Warning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.php#261
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1018): Can't read '.' (error code: 13 - Permission denied)
```

I am running on Web server:
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/5.6.25
libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

Database server:
5.7.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

[image: English errors]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I am sorry, but most of the things that seem important to read in those errors are in a language I can't read. It would help if you state the exact problem you are having, what can you do and what not?

Comment: @Nytrix I think all important phrases are translated into english (about errors). Other is just unnecessary things. But anyway, what field you especially mean?

Comment: You show images of `errors` where I can only read your `queries` as they are code. In your post you only tell a story about you doing something for 3 hours. What is the actuall error you are having? Not the problem, but the error you are getting.

Comment: I updated question. I changed permission of local phpmyadmin folder and these error appeared.

Comment: The `.` you have in there somewhere (you changed there)  it is unable to read and messes up the permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the web server cannot read some (or all) files in the phpmyadmin directory (`(Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)`).

You need to fix the permissions by executing the following commands, assuming the phpmyadmin is located at `/path/to/phpmyadmin`:

```
find /path/to/phpmyadmin -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /path/to/phpmyadmin -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Obviously, you need to replace `/path/to/phpmyadmin` with the actual path.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but It didn't work. I am still not able to create database (permission error)

Comment: Can you please post the exact error (in english) you are getting now?

Comment: still same error "Not enough privilege to view server status." "#13 - Can't get stat of './mydb' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)" and I am running .sql code starting with CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE mydb;

Comment: OK. This is something different to what you described before. It means that the user you are connecting to phpmyadmin, doesn't have the privilege to view existing databases or/and create new databases in mysql server. If the user has the privileges, check the permissions in /var/lib/mysql and make sure everything under this directory is owned by user mysql, group mysql and that the mysql user has full access to all files under that directory.

Comment: Yeah, I second the thought about permissions trouble with the database data directory. This looks like a broken MySQL installation (possibly combined with a broken phpMyAdmin install for the same reasons, but the parent answer would have fixed that).