# MAMP - mysqli_query(): (HY000/6): Error on delete of ....

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, phpmyadmin, mamp

Getting such error when trying to insert table[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin error 13 permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709663/phpmyadmin-error-13-permission-denied)

Comment: that post is about read error, my is about delete...

Comment: This post is about `permissions` for `read/write`. Which seems to be the problem.

Comment: can you pls explain what I should to do, because I am new to PHP,MySQL, phpmyadmin....

Comment: Check the permissions of the directory which is written in the error.

Answer (score -1):

I switched off my antivirus program ...